# How to calculate rolling annualized portfolio alpha/beta in R?

Tags: r, portfolio, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to compute a rolling annualized alpha for a given portfolio using the package PerformanceAnalytics.

So far, I managed to do 2 things:

- get a rolling daily alpha on my daily returns using `chart.RollingRegression(r,r_idx,width = 250, attribute = "Alpha")`
- get a rolling annualized return using `chart.RollingPerformance(r,r_idx,width = 250, FUN="Return.annualized")`. I'd like to transpose that annualization feature to the former function call

I tried to use the FUN parameter in the RollingRegression which doesn't work. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Here's the code you can run that gives the 2 graphs mentioned above from 2 randomly generated returns time series:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2006-12-31"),by="day",length.out = 1000)

set.seed(3542)
ra <- xts(rnorm(1000,0,0.01),order.by = dates)
rb <- xts(rnorm(1000,0,0.01),order.by = dates)

chart.RollingRegression(ra,rb,width = 250, attribute = "Alpha")

chart.RollingPerformance(ra,width = 250, FUN="Return.annualized")
```

Comment: Many thanks for this valuable comment. Trust me (or not), if the outputs (which are basically two graphs) had been of any interest I would have posted it ;)

Comment: What the first useless comment is aimed at, is that we need some code to work from. Provide some data and code that shows what you want to do, and what you've tried.

Comment: I'm sure you'll acknowledge it's a much nicer and constructive way to point the need of code! I've juste edited it. Feel free to give some feedback

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "transpose that annualization feature to the former function call"? 2) `chart.RollingRegression`  does not take a FUN argument but you can pass parameters from `chart.TimeSeries`. 3) `chart.RollingPerformance` can take only one `xts` parameter.  4) Your question is still unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Hi @Biswajit. Thanks for the input. 1) when computing a `RollingPerformance` the rolling return you get over a given period is then annualized. When using `RollingRegression`, that regression is done on daily returns, which will give you a daily alpha. I'd like that alpha to be annualized the same way it's done in `RollingPerformance`. It's what I mean by transposing that annualization feature from one function to another. 2) and 3) I corrected the code but I'm not sure to understand in what `chart.TimeSeries` would be helpful. and 4) I hope it is now!